# VBA + ADO: Insert without select?

Tags: vba, excel, ado, adodb, recordset

I'm writing some Excel VBA for a user to be able to insert records into a SQL Server table, using ADODB. This is working fine:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
conn.Open "<my connection string>"

Dim records As New ADODB.Recordset
records.CursorLocation = adUseClient
records.Open "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [MyTable]", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText

' (Add some stuff here.)

records.UpdateBatch
```

Something's nagging me, though: is it possible to get the recordset pointed at the right table without doing a `SELECT` up front? This could get to be a pretty big table, so `SELECT * FROM [MyTable]` is out. I'm limiting that with a `TOP 1`, but I'm only doing a write, so it feels like I shouldn't have to do that!

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) makes it sound like you can just put a table name in the Source argument:

> Use the optional Source argument to specify a data source using one of the following: a Command object variable, an SQL statement, a stored procedure, **a table name**, [...]

In practice, this doesn't work for me, and all of the following just error out with the message below, like it thinks I'm calling a stored procedure:

```
records.Open "MyTable", conn, ' [...]
records.Open "[MyTable]", conn, ' [...]
records.Open "[dbo].[MyTable]", conn, ' [...]
```

> The request for procedure 'MyTable' failed because 'MyTable' is a table object.

Is there some syntax I'm missing here, or do I just have to go with the `SELECT`?

Comment: You can execute an INSERT statement using the connection object without bothering with a Recordset object.

Comment: Or `select * from [MyTable] where false` will give you an empty recordset...